# How to import and read data from excel file to Python movie hub using fresh tomatoes template

Tags: python, html, css, excel

I'm working on a simple Movie Hub/database project with Python using fresh tomatoes  template that I got from other Dev's and I'm just new so I'm not sure if my codes are corrects or not okay. newbie here <<<----

Now, I would like some help with you guys out there that have massive knowledge of python how to import data from excel to python file and read the data that loops when I need to add another movie list in my excel that I get from imdb.

Here's my codes that I'm working now.

**In my entertainment python file**

**entertainment.py** <<

```
import media
import movie_website
import xlrd

loc = ("sample.xls")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

-------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> **To be remove**

mysteryTeam = media.Movie(
"Mystery Team",
"A story of a murder",
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d0/Mystery_Team.jpg",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMxEe2gnaQY",
"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0357413/",
"4.5 tomatoes out of 5")

iLoveYouMan = media.Movie(
"I Love You Man",
"A story of a man searching for a friend",
"http://www.impawards.com/2009/posters/i_love_you_man_xlg.jpg",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=um5DuTLzw-I",
"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1155056/",
"4 tomatoes out of 5")

hotRod = media.Movie(
"Hot Rod",
"A story of a man chasing his dreams",
"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7f/Hot-rod-poster.jpg",
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhdrA9qz79o",
"https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0787475/",
"3.5 tomatoes out of 5")

--------------------------------------<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< **To be remove**


for rep in range(sheet.nrows):
    get_title = sheet.cell_value(rep,0)
    titles = get_title

    m_title = []
    for rep1 in range(sheet.nrows):
        r1 = str(sheet.cell_value(rep1,1))
        m_title.append(r1)

    m_storyline = []
    for rep2 in range(sheet.nrows):
        r2 = str(sheet.cell_value(rep2,2))
        m_storyline.append(r2)

    m_image = []
    for rep3 in range(sheet.nrows):
        r3 = str(sheet.cell_value(rep3,3))
        m_image.append(r3)

    m_trailer = []
    for rep4 in range(sheet.nrows):
        r4 = str(sheet.cell_value(rep4,4))
        m_trailer.append(r4)

    m_ratings = []
    for rep5 in range(sheet.nrows):
        r5 = str(sheet.cell_value(rep5,5))
        m_ratings.append(r5)


    mediatitle = []
    mediatitle.append(titles)
    mediatitle = 
    media.Movie(m_title,m_storyline,m_image,m_trailer,m_ratings)
    print(mediatitle)
```

**//This one here below is reading the first column in my excel file and send it to movies lists/array which is movie = []**

```
movies = []

for a in range(sheet.nrows):
    get_titles = sheet.cell_value(a,0)
    movies.append(eval(get_titles))

movie_website.open_movies_page(movies)

print(media.Movie.__doc__)
```

**in my excel file**
[image]

Now I want to import my excel data instead of putting it all in my python codes and it will just read the excel data that I inserted from mysteryTeam to hotRod.

I already tried different ideas but I always getting this error:

[image]

Comment: I would recommend using pandas. You can load excel into a dataframe using a single line `pd.read_excel('mymoviefile.xlsx')` . From there you can do all kinds of operations, and it's pretty fast.

Comment: hi, thank you for this and I appreciate your quick help, but much appreciated if you can give me solution for this?